# Drupal Commerce Payment Method: Pay as you Go Options?

Tags: commerce

I'm researching the different payment methods available for Drupal 7 Commerce (Authorize.net, paypal, sagepay, etc.). They all seem to require a monthly price of ~25+ dollars (and sometimes setup fees and other fees). I understand there are fees associated with credit card transactions. I'm starting a new service on my site however and I'm not sure how popular it will be. I would like a payment method that allows me to just pay for each transaction and not necessarily a monthly cost (but also allows me to have the payments made directly on my site - without redirection as it is in paypal wps - to another site), so it looks professional from the get-go.

Any suggestions?